# Correct way to enable .htaccess in Apache, Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I am trying to to enable .htaccess in Apache on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS by changing

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also mod_rewrite is enabled.

But whenever i change AllowOverride **None** to AllowOverride **All** the site goes unresponsive and it keeps on loading.

What could be the possible reason? What is the correct way to enable .htaccess?

Comment: Do you have any directives in your .htaccess file?

Comment: *the site goes unresponsive*. What is in the error logs?

Comment: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
[Thu Sep 24 23:19:24.022733 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22146] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 24 23:19:24.022769 2015] [core:notice] [pid 22146] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 24 23:20:08.241972 2015] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 22146] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

Answer (score 1):

Steps would be like might helpful

- open /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and at the end on
  the file **BEFORE** "`</VirtualHost>`" add this

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/html/>
>         AllowOverride All
>     </Directory>
> ```

- sudo a2enmod rewrite
- sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
[Thu Sep 24 23:19:24.022733 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22146] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 24 23:19:24.022769 2015] [core:notice] [pid 22146] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Sep 24 23:20:08.241972 2015] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 22146] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting